# Running Value for CountDistinct

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

i'm new for SSRS, there is an enhancement where I need to do.

Currently my report is having this format
[before changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDmuN.jpg)

where the expression is =LCASE(CHR(64+RunningValue(Fields!Question.Value, CountDistinct, "Details"))) + "."

However, now i want to change it to this format
[after changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bklcG.jpg)

where when the no. reach from big capital A to Z, the next no. will be start from small capital a until z

So what can i do to make it detect the big capital Z then next will be start from small capital a??

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the number you add to omit non valid characters.
+64 for the first 26 rows, +70 for the next rows

```
=CHR(Iif(RunningValue(Fields!question.Value, CountDistinct,  "Details")>26,70,64) +RunningValue(Fields!question.Value, CountDistinct,  "Details" )) + "."
```

Comment: It seems like changing CHR(number) to make it happen. Can you explain a bit for me regarding this CHR?? I try to search around the internet, it seems like some sort of ASCII table --> http://www.asciitable.com/, if it yes, why change the CHR to 70 where the asciitable is "F" consider as non valid characters??

Comment: For the first 26 rows your char letter will be 26 + rownum eg. for the first row will be 64 + 1 = A. After the 26th row you have to add 70 to your row num to get to the first lowercase letter eg. for row 27 you ll get char 70 + 27 = 97 = a

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I understand how it works now. TQVM

Comment: The correct in my comments is 64 + rownum not 26, but you got what I mean!